# how to create multiple ui page in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

How to create multiple UI pages in `Vaadin` instead of `View`? 
Now I have created pages using view with Navigator?

Example:

```
navigator=new Navigator(UI.getCurrent(),this);
navigator.addView("",new Login(navigator,sf,vs));
```

Comment: Use punctuation to properly format the question

Answer (score 2):

According to the Vaadin API Documentation (btw. first link in Google) you can only have as much as one instance of [UI](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) per browser window:

> The topmost component in any component hierarchy. There is one UI for every Vaadin instance in a browser window. A UI may either represent an entire browser window (or tab) or some part of a html page where a Vaadin application is embedded.

Of course, still you can register multiple UI's on one Server and map them to multiple [VaadinServlet](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServlet.html)'s.